# How to solve issue with terminal screen shrinking while typing?

Tags: kali-linux, gnome-terminal

I'm new to Linux and its terminal, so forgive my errors if any.

### Issue

Whenever I type anything on my terminal the window keeps shrinking. However once the terminal window is maximized this issue never occurs.

### Specifications (according to `uname` command)

- OS: GNU/Linux
- Kernel Version: #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1

### Edit

By terminal here I mean the gnome-terminal.
Only the width and height are affected and the SHIFT and CTRL keys do not affect the window. The only keys affecting the window are the character keys i.e. A-Z, 0-9, and other special symbols and punctuation as well as the TAB key.

Comment: The Linux virtual terminal (like when you press Ctrl+Alt-F1) is not in a window. Surely you mean a terminal emulator software running in a windowing environment. Can you please clarify which it is?

Comment: Yeah you're right, thanks and sorry about that.

Comment: When you say it's shrinking, is it the font size being reduced, or the width or height or both without changing the font size? Does it do it for every keypress? Even things like Ctrl or Shift? What's the window manager?

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve the issue by reinstalling gnome-terminal through xterm.
The exact commands were:

```
aptitude remove gnome-terminal
```

Wait for it to uninstall then

```
aptitude install gnome-terminal
```

I really have no idea what the issue really was but would love to know.

Comment: Possibly fixed by https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7445